# JSZip temporary file location

Tags: javascript, electron, jszip, filesaver.js

I have a electron application using jszip to create a zip file that the user is then able save. Everything works fine but my problem is my application uses the users download folder. Im guessing its making a temporary file. I've submitted my application to the mac store and they want me to use another location instead of the users downloads folder for the temporary file. Is there anyway I can specify the temporary location or maybe something else other then jszip that will do this?

Here is the code I use

```
savePNGButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var zip = new JSZip();
  if (WatermarkText == ""){
    var img = zip.folder("images");
  } else {
    var img = zip.folder(WatermarkText);
  }
  $(".WatermarkPhoto").each(function(index) {
   imgsrc = this.src;
   var DataURL = imgsrc.replace('data:image/png;base64,','');
   img.file(WatermarkText+index+".png", DataURL, {base64: true});
  });
  zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
  .then(function(content) {
      saveAs(content, WatermarkText+".zip");
  });
});
```

[edit]
Looking more into this it looks like my problem is not with JSZip but with chrome or FileSaver.js using the downloads folder as a temp folder for the file before the users chooses where to place the file. Is there anyway I can change the temp location for my electron app?

Comment: It is for the user to decide which folder to download files to.

Comment: Based on [jszip's docs](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/), it doesn't create temporary files. What's the content of the temporary file you're seeing in the user's downloads directory? Could you show some code that minimally reproduces the problem?

Comment: This is before the user chooses where to save the file. I wasn't aware JSZip made a temp file until I used the mac console while running my application and it came up saying my app was accessing the users downloads folder.

Comment: Probably related: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2721

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes across this, I never figured a way around the HTML5 filesystem way of moving the temp file before the users selects the download location. Instead I am using nodejs file system with electrons showSaveDialog. I also had to change JSZip to use .generateNodeStream instead of .generateAsync. Below is my function that I got working for me.

```
savePNGButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var zip = new JSZip();
  if (WatermarkText == ""){
    var img = zip.folder("images");
  } else {
    var img = zip.folder(WatermarkText);
  }
  $(".WatermarkPhoto").each(function(index) {
   imgsrc = this.src;
   var DataURL = imgsrc.replace('data:image/png;base64,','');
   img.file(WatermarkText+index+".png", DataURL, {base64: true});
  });
  // zip.file("file", content);
  // ... and other manipulations
    dialog.showSaveDialog({title: 'Test',defaultPath: '~/'+WatermarkText+'.zip',extensions: ['zip']},(fileName) => {
      if (fileName === undefined){
          console.log("You didn't save the file");
          return;
      }
    zip
    .generateNodeStream({type:'nodebuffer',streamFiles:true})
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName))
    .on('finish', function () {
        // JSZip generates a readable stream with a "end" event,
        // but is piped here in a writable stream which emits a "finish" event.
        console.log("zip written.");
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tested your solution but I'm unable to open the created zip. How do you will set the `fileName` ?